# How to get string from the id's identifier

Tags: java, android

Hello I need to code fast by getting a string from a certain ID's identifier.

For example the ids of my three Textviews are R.id.tv1, R.id.tv2, R.id.tv3.

I want to get a string or a char from the "tv1", basically the '1' to ease up coding and make it faster.

How do I achieve this? Getting getId() just returns an integer of the id, but I really want the string.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How about managing TextViews in array with index?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question... If you meant you want to call `TextView.getText()` easier, then you first need a `TextView` instance... And you could use ButterKnife, or just use `findViewById`, but "coding faster" its all the same number of steps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can create function to convert your ID's to string like

```
public String getCorrespondingString (int resId ) {

    switch(resId){

        case R.id.tv1: return "1";

       case R.id.tv2: return "2";

      case R.id.tv3: return "3";
    }

}
```

Comment: Why would you write a switch? Just do `getResources().getString(resourceId)`, and you can get all the strings for the whole app

Comment: It will not return what question's owner wants, please think twice before down voting

Comment: I feel like the question was asking how to call `getText()` easier (the actual text within the View with those IDs)

Comment: this worked, and answers what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: Then vote for answer, welcome